# How to view the EF Code First Migrations changes before calling 'Update-Database'

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code First Migrations Beta 1.

I would like to see the Migrations and SQL that will run before I actually call 'Update-Database' on the Package Manager Console.

Is there a command to get this information on the Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the link below and search for the section headed Generating an SQL Script.

[ADO.Net Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx)

Run the `Update-Database –TargetDatabase:"database" –Script` command in Package Manager Console

Comment: It's -Target, not -TargetDatabase

Comment: @RalphLavelle OP was asking about Code First Migrations Beta 1.