# Has the -TargetDatabase flag been renamed in EF 4.3 Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using Code-First Migrations Beta up until now and when migrating my database through the Package Manager Console I was able to specify the `-TargetDatabase`, to indicate what database I wanted the migration to apply to, like so:

```
Update-Database -TargetDatabase:"MyLiveDatabase"
```

Since migrations now is included in Entity Framework 4.3, I updated my application to use EF 4.3, but now I cannot set the `-TargetDatabase` flag anymore. When run in the Package Manager Console I get the following error:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TargetDatabase'
```

I read through the [blog post about migrations in EF 4.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) but cannot find any info about it. I also noticed a comment on an [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898762/how-to-view-the-ef-code-first-migrations-changes-before-calling-update-database) saying that the flag should be `-Target` instead of `-TargetDatabase`, but that doesn't seem to work either. The `-Target` flag rather seems to be used to specify which migration I want to migrate to.

Has the `-TargetDatabase` flag been renamed, or how do I specify which database I want to apply the migration to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ConnectionStringName flag, you can see the documentation in the package manager console with

```
get-help update-database
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed! Pretty new to the Package manager console, so the `get-help` command was a nice tip as well. Thanks!